# Wrong behaviour of changes.list : maxresults parameter

Tags: google-drive-api

When I specify the `maxResults` parameter in the change.list request, I expect to get exactly `maxResults` changes if my Drive contains more than `maxResults`. However, I sometimes get less than that, like 635 if i ask fo 637 changes.

Is that a behaviour any of you noticed ?

Comment: indeed... Ill post there as well then. Thanks